# Java ReentrantLock issue

Tags: java, concurrency, reentrantlock

Hello I'm having some issues regarding `Lock's implementation: ReentrantLock`. I'm using a `singleton cache` inside `Spring 3.0(web)`. However when I open several browser tabs at the exact same time, all threads seem to lock, and I get several unnecesary web service calls. Why is this? isn't `lock.tryLock()` thread safe?.
I've tried using an `atomic boolean` instead and the problem persisted.
I also checked the same instance of Cache is referenced.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class SomeCache {

    private List<Object> stuff;
    private Lock lock;

    public SomeCache() { 
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
    }

    public List<Object> getStuff() { 
        if(lock.tryLock()) {
            try{ 
                //call webService
            }
            finally { 
                 lock.unlock(); 
            } 
        }
        else {
           //get other data
        }
        return stuff;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance, cheers.

Comment: That does not compile. Please post actual code.

Comment: How do you know that the function getStuff is called exactly at same time by all the browsers? Try to sysout time in millisec. It may be possible that they are calling web service in sequential order.

Comment: Even if this did compile, it wouldn't exhibit the problem that you are having as you didn't supply us with a main method.  It would be helpful if you could post everything we need to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @jsjunkie It does because if I add a Thread.sleep(5000) after locking, it works as expected.

Comment: Exactly that is what I am saying. When you add sleep your caller doesn't gets out of if block and hence doesn't releases the lock. While in other case it does. I hope I am getting it right!